# Accommodate maximum peoples in tour

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have to arrange a tour. There are N peoples who want to attend the tour. But some of them are enemies with each other. (enemy of enemy may or may not be your enemy. If A is enemy of B, B is also enemy of A) 
If I accommodate a person in my tour, I can not accommodate his enemy.

Now I want to accommodate maximum possible number of persons in the tour. How can I find this number?

ex: If there are 5 tourists, and let's call them A-E. A is enemy with B and D, B is enemy of E, and C is enemy of D.

```
   A    B   C   D   E
  +---+---+---+---+---+
A | - | X |   | X |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
B | X | - |   |   | X |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
C |   |   | - | X |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
D | X |   | X | - |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
E |   | X |   |   | - |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
```

In this case following trips are possible: empty, A, B, C, D, E, AC, AE, BC, BD, ACE, CE, DE etc. Out of these, best tour is ACE as it accommodates 3 tourist and hence the answer 3.

My approach:

- I tried looping and trying combinations with bitmaps, but they are
  very slow.
- I am currently using DFS but trying to find even a better
  method.
- I tried to work by creating friendship graph and prepare some
  spanning tree. But it doesn't work as A can travel with B and B can
  travel with C does not guarantee A and travel with C.
- I tried by creating enemity graph and finding some weak links
  but ended up clueless.

I would be thankful, if somebody can give me a hint or point to a good resource to solve this problem.

Comment: A note adding to what the responders said: this is an NP-hard problem so there's not likely to be a quick solution. Finding the maximum independent set is your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a graph from the tourists :

- each node is a tourist
- if two tourists are enemies draw an edge between them
- find the maximum independent set

There are very well detailed algorithms for finding maximum independent set in this paper:
[Algorithms  for  Maximum  independent  Sets](http://wwwold.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/sat/robson.pdf)

And a parallel approach has been provided in this one:[Lecture Notes on a Parallel Algorithm for Generating a Maximal Independent Set](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vigoda/7530-Spring10/MIS.pdf)

And [this](http://koti.kapsi.fi/~speque/mll-plugin/multilevelLayoutPlugin/MaximalIndependentSetFinder.java) is a java implementation.

Comment: Hi Mok, thank you for all the resources. I would try these out today and update my findings. Hopefully this should work.

Comment: "Maximal" is something different from "maximum" independent set

Comment: @NiklasB. Of course they are, as maximal is and adj. meaning greatest "possible", but I don't get the point. Why do you say this? I mean is this a question or what?

Comment: I'm saying that two of your three links have nothing to do with the maximum independent set problem

Comment: @NiklasB. Oh, yes. I now what you mean, but I think it somehow depends on the OP that wants the maximum or maximal is acceptable, in addition it gives him/her some really good ideas for parallel implementation, and of course he/she can customize it as far as he can.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly create an array of vectors-

```
vector<int> enemy[N];
```

and an array curr[N] telling if he is going or not.
If person x is going, curr[x]=1 else curr[x]=0

now call the given below function as f(0,0).
The answer will be in a global variable named **"maxx"**, which is **0 initially**.

```
 void f(int i,int c)
    {
 // i is the index of current person we are seeing
 // c is the total count of people going till now
    if(i==N)
    {
    if(c>maxx)maxx=c;
    }
    else
    {
    int j,flag=1;
    int sz;
    sz=enemy[i].size();
    if(sz==0)
    {
    //if he has no enemy, he can obviously go
    curr[i]=1;
    f(i+1,c+1);
    }
    else
    {
    for(j=0;j<sz;j++)
    if(curr[enemy[i][j]]==1)
      {
        //if his enemy is already going, he cannot 
        flag=0;
        break;
      }
    if(flag)
    {
     //if none of his enemies till now are going, he can
    curr[i]=1;
    f(i+1,c+1);
    }
    curr[i]=0;
    f(i+1,c);//we will also see what if we dont take him
    }
    }
```

Comment: The above code uses recursive algorithm.
Worst Case Complexity is O(2^N).

Comment: Hi Dhruv, Thank you for your helping hand. But this approach (DFS) is the one I am currently using. Worst case complexity of such algorithm is (2 ^ N). I am looking ahead if I can work for 50 tourist or more.

Comment: Well I can understand. But as this is an NP-Complete problem, you cannot achieve polynomial time.
If there are some additional constraints, they maybe some optimization could work.
If you find some efficient logic, please tell me too :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is indeed NP-complete and there's no way around it. You could try for an heuristic, but in the general case you're just going to have to deal with exponential time.

Comment: @dhruv From notes of radomaj and mok, I used Largest Independent set. I made a graph representing not-enemy with edges and found a clique using BronKerbosch2 algorithm given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm. Output is correct and extremely fast compared to DFS specially when number of vertices are more than 15.

Answer (score 1):

Try making an antagonism graph and then find a [largest independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29#Maximal_independent_set). (Warning: this problem is NP)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I will keep your warning in mind.

Comment: Most problems are in NP, including easy ones.

Comment: Sure. But it's useful to know what kind of big-O performance to expect.